# discord.js presence status offline problem

Tags: discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
let onlineCount = 0;
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("538745138047090708");
guild.members.cache.find(member => {
    if (member.presence.status == "online"){
        onlineCount += 1
    }
})
message.channel.send(`Online Players In Server: ${onlineCount}`)};
```

As you see in picture bot says online players in server is 0 but it's not. There is too many online on server but i don't know how to fix it

[Click For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqLMW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since my reputation is low I cannot comment on your question. As of **27th of October** discord bots need to enable presence intent. You can find that under `applications>BotName>Bot`

If you cannot enable it with button, you need to contact discord support team. [Here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994) is the article