# DiscordJS v12 userinfo command not working

Tags: javascript, promise, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been making a Discord.JS bot and I have an issue with my !userinfo command. There are quite a few issues I am facing but all of them because I don't know how to handle Promises in DiscordJS correctly. No site has been helping me. I have included comments under the lines giving me issues.

```
            const memberemb = message.guild.members.fetch(user);
        Promise.resolve(memberemb).then(function () {
            console.log(memberemb.roles);
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
                .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
                .addField("Nickname:", `${useralso.nickname ? `${useralso.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
                .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
                // always shows offline in status
                .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game ? user.presence.game.name : 'None'}`, true)
                //idk if it shows games correctly
                .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(memberemb.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                //shows date of today not of the joined on date
                .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
                .addField("Roles:", memberemb.roles ? memberemb.roles.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ') : "None", true)
                //shows none as roles
                .setFooter(`Replying to ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
            message.channel.send({ embed });
        });
        break;
```

Please explain how to fix this and also rewrite the code correctly(please) so I can use it for my bot 
Thank you

Comment: Do you have [privileged intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica) enabled?

Comment: yes i switched it on.
now everything works correctly but @everyone is shown in the roles too idk why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issues with presence check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica) or [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662794/discord-js-presence-status-offline-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1). Game will probably be wrong without fixing the that first.

With moment.js, you need to do `moment(currenttime)` before changing the time format.

```js
.addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment(user.joinedAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}`, true)
.addField("Account Created On:", `${moment(user.createdAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}`, true)
```

that should works. (See more in [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/))

Regarding to your roles, `memberemb.roles` is `undefined`.

you will want to get the value from the promise, I put `info` inside the function to do that

```js
Promise.resolve(memberemb).then(function (info) {
```

then within the embed, you can use the `info.roles.caches.map`

```js
.addField("Roles:", info.roles.cache ? info.roles.cache.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ') : "None", true)
```

See more on [how promise works here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: Thank you it woked but, it shows @everyone in the roles too which I don't wanna show
Please tell the fix

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanMithani use this instead, which filter when role is @everyone `info.roles.cache.filter(role=> role.name !=='@everyone').map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ')`